# Cannot use Array of Hashes in RoR fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, fixtures, minitest

I use Ruby On Rails together with a PostgreSQL database. For performance reasons I use a jsonb-field with an array of hashes and not extracting this into a specific table. In the real world this blob looks like

`[ { "row": 1, "price": 0, "column": 1, "status": 1, "index_row": 1, "contingency": 0, "index_column": 1 }, { "row": 1, "price": 0, "column": 2, "status": 1, "index_row": 1, "contingency": 0, "index_column": 2 }... ]`

and works fine.

Now I tried to increase the test coverage and noticed, that I cannot create an array of hashes using the standard fixture approach. Suppose the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.circles
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('circles_id_seq'::regclass),
    blob jsonb
)
```

and a fixture file circles.yml with the following content:

```
templatecircle_1:
  blob: <%= [1, 2] %>
```

This works as expected when running bin/rails test.

```
templatecircle_1:
  blob: {"abc": "def"}
```

This works as expected, too.

However,

```
templatecircle_1:
  blob: <%= [1, {"abc": "def"}] %>
```

yields into an ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:

Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 2 column 11

I even tried to use a workaround as following:

```
templatecircle_1:
  blob: <%= JSON.parse("[1, {\"abc\": \"def\"}]") %>
```

which gives the same error.

Does anyone has an idea, how I can create an array of hashes in RoR fixtures?

Comment: This is very likely a case of premature/bad optimization. Just go with a table. Maintainers/future you will thank you. https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Looks like you tried to store well-structured data in JSON field. This is not what this column type was introduced for. JSON is only for semi-structured, very different, non-relational data. The argument about performance improvement is also questionable, you probably need to index this field with a special index

Comment: If we disregard if this is a good idea or not you just have to use the [correct YAML syntax for arrays and hashes](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started). In general you pretty much never need to ever manually convert anything into JSON and doing so will just result in you storing a string instead of actual JSON objects. The database driver converts whatever you assign into JSON. I don't understand why you're interpolating here either. The whole point of fixtures is KISS and just write the actual literal values.

Comment: Hi Max - thx for referring to the YAML-manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define "array of hashes" field in the YAML fixtures file, use `-` notation for every array element and `:` for every hash key/value pair. Don't need ERB syntax or some JSON parsing. Just such structure:

```yaml
# test/fixtures/circles.yml

templatecircle_1:
  blob:
    - row: 1
      price: 0
      column: 1
      status: 1
      index_row: 1
      contingency: 0
      index_column: 1
    - row: 1
      price: 0
      column: 2
      status: 1
      index_row: 1
      contingency: 0
      index_column: 2
```

After that you can call inside your test

```rb
Circle.first.blob
# => [{
#      "row"=>1,
#      "price"=>0,
#      "column"=>1,
#      "status"=>1,
#      "index_row"=>1,
#      "contingency"=>0,
#      "index_column"=>1
#    },
#      "row"=>1,
#      "price"=>0,
#      "column"=>2,
#      "status"=>1,
#      "index_row"=>1,
#      "contingency"=>0,
#      "index_column"=>2
#    }]
```

As you see it will be parsed automatically

---

So for `[1, {"abc": "def"}]` the structure will be:

```yaml
# test/fixtures/circles.yml

templatecircle_1:
  blob:
    - 1
    - abc: def
```

And in Ruby:

```rb
Circle.first.blob
# => [1, {"abc"=>"def"}]
```

---

It's also possible to use such syntax (just remove ERB from your original attempt):

```yaml
# test/fixtures/circles.yml

templatecircle_1:
  blob: [1, {"abc": "def"}]
```

And in Ruby:

```rb
Circle.first.blob
# => [1, {"abc"=>"def"}]
```

---

If you still need ERB by some reasons, you can use `to_json` method

```yaml
# test/fixtures/circles.yml

templatecircle_1:
  blob: <%= [1, { "abc": "def" }].to_json %>
```

And in Ruby:

```rb
Circle.first.blob
# => [1, {"abc"=>"def"}]
```

Comment: That did the trick. I cannot fully omit ERB as I need 100 entries and use ERB for a better  maintainability, but I can take it from there. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @zaphodbln_, I've updated the answer with ERB, you need `to_json` in this case

Comment: I now have

```templatecircle_1:
  blob:
  <% 100.times do |i| %>
    - row: <%= (1 + i / 10) %>
      price: 0
      column: <%= (1 + i % 10) %>
      status: <%= Circle::SeatOccupancyFree %>
      index_row: <%= (1 + i / 10).to_s %>
      contingency: 0
      index_column: <%= (1 + i % 10).to_s %>
  <% end %>```

and all works as expected